# Need to maintain constant water pressure from source

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, water

[image: Water tank setup]

Was trying to setup a drip water irrigation .The initial setup was as follows -
1. Water tank tank at top of first floor
2. Siphoned a tube to backyard and provide water to plants

The drawback here was that with the water level going down in the main tank the pressure dropped and the drip emitters stopped providing water at a point .

Am contemplating of a similar setup upgrade as shown in the image.
1. Water from main tank is drawn to a mini tank with float valve to avoid overflow
2. Mini tank feeds the plants with water

Can you please confirm if this setup could ensure a constant pressure and the emitter need not be readjusted for pressure variations?

If there are better alternatives please suggest them too. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A float valve to maintain a fairly consistent water level, and thereby more constant pressure at delivery, is a reliable, workable, and relatively inexpensive solution. Another method would be to use a pressure regulator valve instead of the secondary tank system, but it may be hard to find a consistent, inexpensive valve for these low pressures.

Comment: Thanks Adrian for your inputs. Couldn't give a thumbs up as I do not have enough reputation points for that.